# How do I store the same values in a session?

Tags: php, session

I'm building a checkout system, and I'm trying to add products to a session variable. But I'm stuck on how I should save them. How can I save for example 5 products?

I try to use something like this, but that doesn't work:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['productIds']['id'] .= $_POST['productid'];
$_SESSION['cart']['productPrices']['price'] .= $_POST['price'];
```

The output is something like this (twice a product with id 2 and price 20):

```
Array ( [productIds] => Array ( [id] => 22 ) [productPrices] => Array( [price] => 2020 )
```

I would like it to be saved as an array, what's the best approach for this?

Comment: Do you know how to use *arrays*...?

Comment: Does the output surprise you?  What have you expected instead?

Comment: `.=` is not a valid [array operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), use `+=` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should treat the session variable as an array instead of string. Append to it using the `[]` operator:

```
$_SESSION['cart']['products'][] = array(
    'id' => $_POST['productid'],
    'price' => $_POST['price'],
);
```

You can also use `array_push()` if you want. Later you can iterate over the products like:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['products'] as $product) {
    echo $product['id'], ': ', $product['price'], "\n";
}
```